# How to run BigQuery for Selection of last month Records?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get records from BigQuery Table for last month. I found that my column is in TimeStamp format, that's why it is giving an error.
No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) at [4:21]

Table Structure
[image]

Query

```
SELECT user_mobile,count(*) as total_customer FROM `Project.Dataset.Table` cr
where cr.DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
group by user_mobile
having count(*) >=1;
```

Please guide how can I use timestamps in my query to get my required results. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#current_timestamp) and [TIMESTAMP_SUB()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_sub) instead:

```
SELECT user_mobile,count(*) as total_customer 
FROM `Project.Dataset.Table` cr
where cr.created_at BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
group by user_mobile
having count(*) >=1;
```

or convert `created_at` to date with `DATE(cr.created_at)`

Comment: Sergey thank you for your help. Unfortunatly its not working and giving this error again.No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) at [5:21]

Comment: There was a typo. Please copy-paste again.